Is it possible to develop a backend API (no UI) to fetch Microsoft Teams transcripts using graph APIs for multiple tenants?
I'm trying to build a backend app to fetch the Teams meeting transcripts within my tenant and in future it may be used to fetch transcripts for multiple tenants as well. So, I am exploring the app-only access for this and would like to know the steps and the difficulties around this solution. Can it be done as a standalone web API or do I need to create a Teams Bot to achieve this.
I tried app-only access and added these API permissions in portal.azure.com.

OnlineMeetings.Read.All
OnlineMeetingTranscript.Read.All

And I'm stuck how can I expand my API to multiple tenants.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

To fetch Teams meeting transcripts using app-only access, register your app in Azure AD, add OnlineMeetings.Read.All and OnlineMeetingTranscript.Read.All permissions, and grant admin consent. Use the client credentials flow to get a token and call Microsoft Graph API. For multi-tenant support, set your app as "Multi-tenant" and handle tenant-specific consent dynamically.

Thanks for the reply! How do I take consents from the other tenants if I don't have any user interface? Can it be done via configuration on the azure portal? I'm checking if there is any documentation for the same, but still no luck!
